# Calling async function inside non-async function in React-Native - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, async-await

This is what I'm trying do in React-Native. Async functions are making calls to firebase.

```
async functionOne() {
    asyncStuffHappens
}

functionTwo() {
    this.functionOne();
}
```

`this.functionOne();` is undefined. I'm not sure how to call an async function from another function.

Comment: Where do this two functions live? Inside a component? What should this be bound to?

Comment: This lives inside a component. `functionTwo` is being called from a TouchableOpacity's onPress event handler. I resolved my issue by correctly binding `this` when I called the function inside the onPress. The IFFE isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: No doubt binding it in constructor is the best but just for information, you can also use `arrow function` to handle these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @lonesomeday said, `this.functionOne()` is all I needed. My issue was I wasn't binding `this` properly in the onPress of the TouchableOpacity I was calling it from.

Answer (score 27):

Like this:

```
async functionOne() {
    asyncStuffHappens
}

functionTwo() {
    (async () => {
        await this.functionOne();
    })();
}
```

This is called an [IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). It's a function executed right after it's created

Comment: This is completely unnecessary here, as the return value is never used. `this.functionOne()` is all you need.

Comment: The code provided didn't show everything. I'm guessing that a value might be returned or that another action needs to be done after the async one. Otherwise, he/she wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: Then this may or may not be a good solution. An IIAFE is not normally necessary.

Comment: You're right on this, an IFEE is not necessary in this case